# Passing Laravel Collection to Vue

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to return customers from model Customer where id < 10. I do have some in the database.

```
$customers = Customer::where('id', '<', 10)->get();
return json_encode(['customers' => $customers]);
```

The above code will error out "Trailing data"
[image: Trailing data error]

and when I try to dd($customers), I get a list of the collection Customer
[image: collection customer dump]

I have no idea why I keep getting that and why the model is returning raw collection and not an object of the list of customers???

It seems like a null date "updated_at" field is causing the error. don't know why!

## Solved By:

on the Customer model I had to do:

```
//ask Laravel to not manage default date columns
public $timestamps = false;
```

also I to mutate those columns:

```
public function setDateRemindedAttribute($value)
{
    if (strlen($value)) {
        $this->attributes['date_reminded'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value);
    } else {
        $this->attributes['date_reminded'] = null;
    }
}

public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    if (strlen($value)) {
        $this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value);
    } else {
        $this->attributes['updated_at'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with some date field.

Comment: `get()` method returns a `collection`, that's the expected behavior. What are you expecting?. Try `->get()->toJson()`, but you probably have an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) related to a date field that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have already `->toJson()` and it did throw the same error as above.

Comment: Show us the `Customer.php` file.

Comment: @Kal : did you try `response()->json()` ?

Comment: yes did, but please look at my edited question

Comment: @Kal set the default value for those fields (updated_at and created_at) as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, I think they can't be null.

Comment: share vue code also and response from network tab, and error if any ?

Comment: Share also your Customer model.

Answer (score 0):

Use [response()->json()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses) like this

```
$customers = Customer::where('id', '<', 10)->get();
return response()->json(['customers' => $customers]);
```

Comment: Or simply just `return compact('customers')`;

Comment: @Alfa : response is as JSON for vue not for laravel blade

Comment: @user2486 It returns json response actually if request is ajax :) (related to Alfa answer)